# Rotating / align a dodecahedron face to a flat plane face - unexpected results

Tags: geometry, snapping

I'm trying to rotate a dodecahedron face to align with a flat plane face.

I watched a video see below and
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qhx6C6wGVns

[image: img1]

When I rotate a dodecahedron's face to align with a face on a flat plane the dodecahedron face doesn't align with the face of the plane.

[image: img2]

What it should look like when it snaps to face
[image]

link to file with origin at the face center https://pasteall.org/blend/57f7b97899d544dd84303b122ea8621d

Comment: maybe you need to correctly orientate the origin of your object (align it with the face you want), please share it if it still doesn't work: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: link to file with origin at the face center https://pasteall.org/blend/57f7b97899d544dd84303b122ea8621d

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That video is maybe not as good as it could be, because it doesn't deal with likely problems people will have-- like you are having here, with your dodecahedron.

When you enable snapping to face with align rotation to target, Blender isn't aligning the rotation of the nearest selected object's face to the snapped face.  It's aligning the object's +Z axis with the snapped face.  If we enable the display of axes on your object, we can see exactly what that is:

[image]

In the tutorial, the video author had object Z axes that were aligned with the way they wanted the face to snap.  In your case, you don't.  That's why it worked for them but not for you.

Now, if we want, we can align the origin with the face.  Enter edit mode, select the face we want to snap, and "create orientation" (ctrl alt space for me.)  Then in object mode, enable Origins in sidebar/tool/options/affect only and use "align to transform orientation" operation (perhaps from searchbar, perhaps from object->transform menu.)  This will set the Z axis of the object pointing out from the face you selected:

[image]

With affect only origins still set, we could rotate this in its local X or Y axis by 180 degrees so that Z axis points inward, which will then align via snapping with our box.  After setting the origin, don't forget to turn off affect only origins.

[image]

Yes, this is tedious, particularly if we want to do this with any arbitrary face, particularly if we want to animate this object doing it with multiple faces.  I am not a fan of Blender's snapping to begin with and generally prefer rigging objects to bones or empties that use shrinkwrap constraints.

Comment: Thanks that did it...